# React TypeScript right way to set select value and state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, select

I am trying to learn using TypeScript in my React projects.

I made a type for the incoming data format (name and url).

```js
type PokedexType = {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}
```

The data returned from the *API* is an array of objects (with name and url).

```js
{
"results": [
        {
            "name": "national",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/1/"
        },
        {
            "name": "kanto",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/2/"
        },
        // ...
    ];
}
```

In my `useEffect()`, I am storing these objects in a state with `setState()`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  api.get('/pokedex')
    .then((response) => {
      setPokedex(response.data.results);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Because the API returns an array, I am confused about the correct way to setup `useState()`.

```js
// this works
const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState<Array<PokedexType>>([{ name: "", url: "" }]);
// these also work
const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState<PokedexType>({ name: "", url: "" });
const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState<Array<PokedexType>>();
const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState(); // (with checking)
```

I understand that specifying type is for type checking, but if the state is overwritten immediately, does this matter?

I am trying to set the states name (`i`.name) as value for my select, what would be the correct way to do this? Since the state is now an array, how can I set the value to the corresponding property (like this)?

```html
<select value={pokedex.name}>
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your question. Are you asking what the point of using types is? Do you have a secondary question about how to change the value of an item in an array using state?

Comment: shouldn't `useState<Array<PokedexType>>([{ name: "", url: "" }]);` just be `useState<PokedexType[]>([{ name: "", url: "" }]);`?

Comment: @azium they are indeed 2 separate questions, I will try to make that clear

Comment: @kimbaudi both ways do the same thing (`arrname[]` and `Array<arrname>`)

Comment: The default linter rule is non-complex types (i.e. a single pre-defined type) should use `type[]` and a complex types (defined inline / composite types) should use `Array<{ name: string; url: string; }>` or `Array<typeOne & typeTwo>`. I do not know if this is a preference only linter rule or has something to do with type resolution speed.

Comment: @JacobSmit I didn't know there was a preferred way, thank you for pointing that out, but in the end it wouldn't change much to the outcome right?

Comment: If you are after an Array of PokedexType either will be fine, even `useState([{ name: "", url: "" }]);` would be fine as the inferred type would meet all the requirements of PokedexType (NOTE: I would not do this, as if you change PokedexType you would have to remember to also update the `useState` initial value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just say `pokedex.name`. `pokedex` is an array, so you have to loop through that array. e.g.

```js
//just a mock, will come from your ajax request
const pokedex = [
    {
        "name": "national",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/1/"
    },
    {
        "name": "kanto",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokedex/2/"
    }
]

const Select = () => ( <select > 
      {pokedex.map(el => < option value = {el.name} >{el.name}</option>)}
</select>)


        // Render it
        ReactDOM.render( <
          Select / > ,
          document.getElementById("react")
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Take also a look at interfaces:

```
interface IPokedex {
    name: string;
    url: string;
}

const [pokedex, setPokedex] = useState<IPokedex[]>([{ name: "", url: "" }]);
```

Comment: Ok but the parent `select` tag also has a value prop, what should I bind to this value?

Comment: Your `pokedex` result has no preselected value, so you can keep the `select value` empty. In that way, it will manage the selection itself. If you wish to preselect it or to control the selection yourself, then you should take a look at the React Controlled Components https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components.
But what is your final Goal?

Comment: Oh ok, I thought setting a value to the select was needed for it to display the right option, I guess I can just leave it out then if my `<option>`'s have a value.

Comment: I adjusted my code snippet, it has no preselected value anymore. Try it out.
Did this answer your question?